# During tesing my model TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, tensorflow

During tesing my model on gender classification, the error comes:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

```
    if not FLAGS.multi_crop:
        image = cv2.resize(image, (FLAGS.input_size, FLAGS.input_size))
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
        result = sess.run(predict_label, feed_dict={image_batch: image,
                                                    label_batch: None,
                                                    training_or_not: False})

        label = np.argmax(result, axis=1)
```

error:

```
 File "C:/Users/x/Desktop/毕设/rude-carnie-master/rude-carnie-master/train1.py", line 443, in main
    inference(image)

  File "C:/Users/x/Desktop/毕设/rude-carnie-master/rude-carnie-master/train1.py", line 426, in inference
    training_or_not: False})

  File "D:\software\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "D:\software\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1109, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)

  File "D:\software\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to cast a float or something to an integer...but that variable actually = None. What is happening on line 443 of train1.py?

Comment: first you should check what you have in `image`.  If you use `cv2` to read it from file or get from webcam then it may gives `None` instead of rasing error when it couldn't get image - and later you may get error when it will try to use `None`. So you should use `if image is not None: ... your code ...`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Matt line 443 of train1.py is main function and I use cv2 to read my test bmp file
`def main(_):

      image = cv2.imread(FLAGS.test_pic)

      inference(image)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    tf.app.run()`